# Unpack and print tuples in pandas dataframe column

Tags: pandas, tuples

I have a pandas dataframe, **df**:

```
Search term                                 Match type
second hand proace toyota crew cab sale     Broad match
bmw m5 buy                                  Exact match
```

I would like to apply ngrams from nltk package to the **Search term** column. 
The ngrams function will return a tuple.

I would like only the Phrases as the final output, like this:

```
Phrases
second hand
hand proace
proace toyota
toyota None
bmw m5
m5 buy
buy None
```

This is what I've figured out so far:

```
df['Phrases'] = df['Search term'].apply(lambda x: list(ngrams([x for x in x.split()], 2, pad_right=True)))
```

This is the output from the code above:

```
Search term                   Match type      Phrases
second hand proace toyota     Broad match     [('second', 'hand'), ('hand', 'proace'), ('proace', 'toyota'), ('toyota', None)]
bmw m5 buy                    Broad match     [('bmw', 'm5'), ('m5', 'buy'), ('buy', None)]
```

How do I unpack all the tuples in the list and print them without the comma and brackets?

Comment: try `['{} {}'.format(i, j) for i, j in np.concatenate(df.Phrases)]` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on @Chris A answer:

```
['{} {}'.format(i, j) for i, j in np.concatenate(df.Phrases)]
```

The result will be in a list, so you can transform it into a dataframe using `pd.DataFrame()` .

If it is a trigram, simply change it to:

```
['{} {} {}'.format(i, j, k) for i, j, k in np.concatenate(df.Phrases)]
```